# How to get an array of dates given a start date and a time-period?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have-
startDate - a start date,
timePeriod - a fixed period

I have to generate an array of dates using the two.

for example, 
startDate is 2020-04-17 and the timePeriod is 10,

I need an array of Dates starting from startDate till 10 days i.e 
[2020-04-17, 2020-04-18, 2020-04-19, .....2020-04-26]

Comment: Definitely not possible, unfortunately.  The values cannot appear out of nowhere.  You can represent them differently and then design your code to use the simplified or reduced representations, such as a range or, as you have mentioned, 10 days, or a mathematical formula that can represent the value as it would be represented in memory with something like an ArrayBuffer, but there's no way to make 10 values appear out of thin air.  And unfortunately you'd still have to loop over it, because you can't typecast the pointer to a date like you might in C++ on the ArrayBuffer.

Comment: please specify what is the reason you need this array, then we might offer a better way of accomplishing same goal

Answer (score 0):

If you can use moment.js then use the below function to get the dates:

```
function getDatesArray(startdate, timePeriod){
  var result = [];
    for(var i=0; i<timePeriod;i++){

     var newDate = moment(startdate, "YYYY-MM-DD").add('days', i).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
     result.push(newDate)


  }

  return result;
}

console.log(getDatesArray("2020-02-26", 10));
```

and without moment you can implement with this code.

```
function getDatesArray(date, timePeriod) {
    var dateAr = [date]
    for(i=0;i<timePeriod-1;i++){
      var newdate = new Date(date);
      newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate() + i);
      var dd = newdate.getDate();
      var mm = newdate.getMonth() + 1;
      var y = newdate.getFullYear();
            dateAr.push(y+"-"+mm+"-"+dd)

    }
    return dateAr;
}

getDatesArray("2020-2-27", 10);
```